# Best way to synch files across the internet? Free tools?

Tags: windows, sync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to sync two computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/65025/best-way-to-sync-two-computers)

I need to be able to synch files across the internet, preferably in a transparent way (i.e. via a service), though that that isn't a necessity. DropBox is no good - not enough space and it forces you to store things within its own hierarchy. Plus I have no need for internet storage - all storage will be on my own machines sitting in my LANs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/65025/best-way-to-sync-two-computers

Comment: You might as well increase your accept ration, so people are more willing to answer your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows live sync it's awesome!
It's exactly what you need, and there is also a mac os client

Comment: What exactly does Windows Live Sync do? Same thing as what he's describing here? Just curious.

Comment: Windows live sync enables you to share on the internet 20 folders, tied to your windows live account. You can share this folder with another windows live accounts, or choose to keep it private. It is very good. There is no internet storage.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Linux, I would say rsync + crontab ?

Comment: sorry, should have said - windows

Answer (score 1):

Using [rsync for Windows](http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html).

Answer (score 0):

[CrashPlan](http://b3.crashplan.com/consumer/index.html) might suit your needs.  Free for personal use.

Comment: I'm probably reading this incorrectly, but it looks like you still need to pay to use the unlimited online backup, which is only free for 30 days. Otherwise, if you plan on using another folder or computer, or a friend's CrashPlan account, it's free.

Comment: @Isxek: Yes, the free version only allows you to back up from one computer to another, which is what the OP asked for, "...I have no need for internet storage - all storage will be on my own machines sitting in my LANs."  He would set up CrashPlan on two computers, preferably at different locations (e.g., one at home one at work), and keep them synced.